# Mostrar e Ocultar Linhas de Tabela

Tags: php, javascript, table

Existe no código o botão exibe/oculta, referenciado uma função JavaScript, porém, o botão só funciona trazendo o último registro do banco, nunca o registro referente a linha que ele está e só exibe depois da primeira linha da tabela.

Por exemplo, mesmo eu clicando o botão que está referenciando o 4º registro, ele exibe a `<div>` na abaixo da 1º linha de resultados da tabela, como eu faço para que o `$row['chave']` fique abaixo de cada linha de acordo com sua ordem na tabela e só exiba ou oculte de acordo a ação no botão, segue abaixo código;

```
foreach($result as $row) {

$database = date_create($row['expira']);
$datadehoje = date_create();
$resultado = date_diff($database, $datadehoje);
$intervalo = date_interval_format($resultado, '%a');

if($intervalo > 5){
    $classe = "";
}else if($intervalo <= 2){
    $classe = "color-alert";
}else if($intervalo > 2 && $intervalo <=5){
    $classe ="color-warn";
}


//echo $datab;
// echo $datac;
echo '<tr class="'.$classe.'">';

echo '<td ><center>'.$row['cliente'].'</center></td>';
echo '<td ><center>'.$row['cnpj'].'</center></td>';
echo '<td ><center>'.$row['registro'].'</center></td>';
echo '<td ><center>'.$row['versao'].'</center></td>';
echo '<td ><center>'.$row['expira'].'</center></td>';
echo '<td><center> '
. '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="editar.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'
        . '<i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Editar</a>    </td>';
echo'<td><button id="btnExibeOculta" class="btn" onclick="ocultarExibi();">'
. 'Exibir/Ocultar</button></td>';
echo'</tr>';
echo'<tr>    
    <td>
    <div id="dvConteudo" style="display:none;" >'.$row['chave'].'</div>
    </td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Código Javascript:

```
<script>

    var visibilidade = true;
    function ocultarExibir() { 
        if (visibilidade) {
            document.getElementById("dvConteudo").style.display = "none";
            visibilidade = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("dvConteudo").style.display = "block";
            visibilidade = true;
            }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos ver se eu consigo de ajudar:

Você esqueceu o 'r' na chamada da função Javascript ocultarExibir() em:

```
echo'<td><button id="btnExibeOculta" class="btn" onclick="ocultarExibi();">'
```

Bem, se você quiser exibir $row['chave'] assim que o código carregar mude
    display:none;
para
    display:block;
em:

```
<div id="dvConteudo" style="display:none;" >'.$row['chave'].'</div>
```

Altere seu código Javascript para:

```
<script>

  function ocultarExibir() { 

      var visibilidade = document.getElementById("dvConteudo").style.display;

      if ( visibilidade == "none") {
        document.getElementById("dvConteudo").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("dvConteudo").style.display = "none";
      }

  }

</script>
```